# Bndtools output to console

Tags: java, osgi, bnd, blueprint-osgi, bndtools

I've just started using bndtools for my OSGi projects but I can't seem to configure the project to get information output (Hibernate information, Spring DM information) to the console (in Eclipse). I'm having a hard time with the project as I'm getting no feedback and no log files seem to be created.

JLove

Comment: What is the relation to bndtools or bnd? This seems to be more about logging in Equinox?

Comment: @Peter Kriens  Hi Peter, It may be my lack of understanding, I've only started having this issue since I changed over to using bnd (i.e. before hand I would get hibernate information output to the console, now I only get the actual equinox/or felix console which is making it difficult to progress as I'm using Spring DM to register my services. Could you offer any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the problem that your logging library does not see the properties. Since these properties are looked up as a resource they can only be seen when in the same module. I know there are solutions with a fragment (yuck). I am not a user of all these logging APIs but you might want to look at PAX logging. I think they provide a proper setup for logging of most major logging libraries in OSGi.